# Bulk importing of unanswered questions from mathoverflow

Tags: discussion

Mathoverflow has a number of unanswered statistics questions. Should they be bulk imported here to see if they get answers, or should we just wait to see if the questioners want to repost?

https://mathoverflow.net/unanswered/tagged?tagnames=st.statistics&page=1&tab=votes

Answer (score 2):

I'd say wait and see if the questioner's repost; perhaps leave them comments suggesting that they do so.  While it is nice to have a large database of questions and answers, if we do a bulk import it is possible that we'll find ourselves answering questions that benefit no one.

Answer (score 1):

I think a naive bulk import would be a bad idea.

1. I don't think we are currently suffering from a shortage of questions.
2. I think questions do better when the person posing the question can answer queries, provide initial up votes.
3. The reason some of the questions may have been unanswered is because they are poor questions.

Nevertheless, I think it would be a good idea to "cherry-pick" a few very good question and post them.